# what's wrong with this Android datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have this here on date picker.

for example if I select December 11 2011 shows ==>2011:11:11

or jun 11 2012 shows ==> 2012:0:11 !!!

```
private void Date_picker_dialog()
{

    OnDateSetListener datelistener = new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "Date set: " + year + ":" + monthOfYear + ":" + dayOfMonth, 3000).show();

        }
    };
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityMain.this, datelistener, 2011, 11, 11);
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: You have to use (monthOfYear + 1) becz by default it start with 0....

Comment: Months are enumerated from 0 so when you get your date from the datepicker with month set to December you get monthOfYear = 11

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this will help you....
    OnDateSetListener datelistener = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
       Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "Date set: " + year + ":" + (monthOfYear+1) + ":" + dayOfMonth, 3000).show();
    }
    };
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityMain.this, datelistener, 2011, 11, 11);
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void callDatePic() {
    new DatePickerDialog(AddFriendActivity.this, d, c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        date =  dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;          
        c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "Date set: " + date,3000).show();

    }
    }

};
```

try this 
hope this will helps you